# What's the difference between 真（しん）and 真実（しんじつ）？

Tags: word-choice

The dictionary definitions appear to be the same though I can only find usage of 真実.

Answer (score 1):

I do know that one difference, at least, is that 真{しん}(の) by itself can be used as an adjective to say a "true (whatever)". For example, you could say 真{しん}の勇気{ゆうき} for "true courage," or 真{しん}の満足{まんぞく} for "true satisfaction." This is the way I see 真{しん} being used most frequently (outside of certain anime titles like 真{しん}・ゲッターロボ).

EDIT: And according to the comments below, you can use 真実の for this purpose as well. That basically throws any meaningful answer I had out the window. Sorry!

[goo's dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/113262/meaning/m1u/%E7%9C%9F/) also mentions the phrase 真｛しん｝に迫｛せま｝る. It literally means "approaching truth," and you can use it to describe something that is very realistic, like a 真｛しん｝に迫｛せま｝る映画｛えいが｝, or a realistic movie, a movie "approaching the truth." I have seen this in books on occasion. You can't replace the 真｛しん｝ here with 真実｛しんじつ｝ since it's a fixed expression.

One of the best ways I've found to get quick usage examples of words is to look them up in Japanese dictionaries, such as goo's (based on Daijisen) and [Weblio's](http://www.weblio.jp/) (based on Daijirin). Most of the time they'll have short example phrases for each definition, which can help you get a feel for how they're used. If you're lucky, goo will even have a thesaurus entry for it (which, in this case, it does) that will have even more usage tips.

Comment: I added furigana, please check that I did not make many mistakes. For future: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/

Comment: We do say 真実の勇気 or 真実の愛, and they mean much the same as 真の勇気 and 真の愛.

Comment: I stand corrected!